# can't scrape inside script tag using BeautifulSoup web scraping

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, screen-scraping

Hi i am trying to scrape data using beautifulsoup from a table and the table is inside the script tag and each td is bind with data-bind. kindly help me how to do this task i tried and searched many times but failed. I am new to scraping please help me by solving this problem.

---

```
<script type="text/html" id="searchResultTemplate">
    <table class="searchResultTable">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <td data-bind="click: function (data, event) { setSortInfo(SortInfoArray()[0]) }">Given Name</td>
                <td data-bind="click: function (data, event) { setSortInfo(SortInfoArray()[1]) }">Family Name</td>
                <td data-bind="click: function (data, event) { setSortInfo(SortInfoArray()[2]) }">Business</td>
                <td data-bind="click: function (data, event) { setSortInfo(SortInfoArray()[3]) }">Suburb</td>
                <td data-bind="click: function (data, event) { setSortInfo(SortInfoArray()[4]) }">State</td>
                <td data-bind="click: function (data, event) { setSortInfo(SortInfoArray()[5]) }">Country</td>
                <td>Map</td>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody data-bind="template: { name: 'agentItemTemplate', foreach: Result }">
        </tbody>
    </table> </script>
```

---

i ran the below code to scrape above table data.

```
import bs4
from urllib.request import urlopen as uRequest
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup

my_url = 'https://www.mara.gov.au/search-the-register-of-migration-agents/'
# opening up connection, grabing the page
uClient = uRequest(my_url)
# reading whole html of the page into variable
page_html=uClient.read()
#closing the connection with page
uClient.close()
# parsing the html page into a variable
page_soup=soup(my_url,"html.parser")
# to view h1 tags page_soup.h1
# create list of all divs having class item-container
table=page_soup.findAll("table",{"class":"searchResultTable"})
rows=table.findAll('tr')
if len(rows)>0:
    for row in rows:
        print(row)
```

Answer (score 1):

The website uses an api to retrieve the data .

```
import requests , csv , os

def SaveAsCsv(list_of_rows):
    try:
        with open('data.csv', mode='a',  newline='', encoding='utf-8') as outfile:
            csv.writer(outfile).writerow(list_of_rows)
            print(" saved successully\n")
    except PermissionError:
        print("Please make sure data.csv is closed\n")

def Search(location):
    url = 'https://www.mara.gov.au/api/agentsearch'
    head = {
        'Accept': '*/*',
        'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br',
        'Accept-Language': 'en,en-US;q=0.9,ar;q=0.8',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        'Host': 'www.mara.gov.au',
        'Referer': 'https://www.mara.gov.au/search-the-register-of-migration-agents/',
        'Sec-Fetch-Mode': 'cors',
        'Sec-Fetch-Site': 'same-origin',
        'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/79.0.3945.79 Safari/537.36',
        'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest'
    }
    parmters = {
        'DelimitedStartWithLetterFilter[FieldName]': 'DisplayBusiness.Name',
        'DelimitedStartWithLetterFilter[LetterString]': '',
        'DelimitedStartWithLetterFilter[Label]': 'Show+All',
        'DelimitedStartWithLetterFilter[IsSelected]': 'false',
        'DelimitedStartWithLetterFilter[ContainsData]': 'true',
        'Keyword': '',
        'Location': location,
        'BusinessName': '',
        'IsNoFee': '',
        'IsPractitioner': '',
        'AgentFamilyName': '',
        'AgentGivenName': '',
        'AgentName': '',
        'AgentMARN': '',
        'SortInfo[SortField]': '',
        'SortInfo[IsAscending]': 'false',
        'PagingInfo[PageIndex]': 0,
        'PagingInfo[PageSize]': 20
    }
    res = requests.get(url,headers=head,params=parmters)
    if res.status_code == 200 :
        return res.json()
def Extract():
    data = Search('AUSTRALIA') # Pass in the location word
    for row in data['Result']:
        first_name    = row['Name']['GivenName']
        family_name   = row['Name']['FamilyName']
        business_name = row['PrimaryBusiness']['Name']
        Suburb        = row['PrimaryBusiness']['Address']['Suburb']
        State         = row['PrimaryBusiness']['Address']['State']
        country       = row['DisplayBusiness']['Address']['Country']
        full_address  = row['DisplayBusiness']['Address']['FullAddress']

        SaveAsCsv([first_name,family_name,business_name,Suburb,State,country,full_address])

if os.path.isfile('data.csv') and os.access('data.csv', os.R_OK):
    print("File data.csv Already exists \n")
else:
    SaveAsCsv([ 'Given Name','Family Name','Business Name','Suburb','State','country','full_address'])
Extract()
```

Output is csv sheet
[image]

Comment: So much thanks Ahmed Soliman to answer this question. You did a good job for me by solving this issue but there is a problem this gives only first row text i want to get all rows text. The table has 446 rows 20 rows per page etc. Please write code to gel all rows data.

Comment: @WasimSahi I Scraped the content of the url you provided . provide html sample and I'll update the code for you .

Comment: The given url has a complete table with many rows when loaded into browser but when i view page source only one row with tds you scraped displays. I think each row generates dynamically using JavaScript. You please load the url and view page source for me.

Comment: @WasimSahi the results you are talking about only get added to the dom when you hit the search button , so can you give me some valid search inputs ?

Comment: Dear Ahmed Soliman you just have to write AUSTRALIA in business location and then hit search.

Comment: @WasimSahi check the answer now . :)

Comment: Thanks Dear Ahmed Soliman for doing a great effort for me. I am so happy. You such a good developer. Now the problem is that we want to scrape data on next page which displays after clicking the family name link. How to do this automatically?

Comment: @WasimSahi the script already gives you all the results the website returns m if you tried another search word that gave you more results please let me know (I'm using Egyptian ip)